# Linking using href with filter value

Tags: html

I have a section on a page with filter based on drop down list selection.
The select commands are:

```
<select id="dropdown">
         <option class="filter" value="all" selected>All types</option>
         <option class="filter" value="type1">Type 1</option>
         <option class="filter" value="type2">Type 2</option>
         <option class="filter" value="type3">Type 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to link to a filtered types of this page, for example the link titled “Type 1” will direct to “page.html” with filter value ”type1”, the link titled “Type 2” will direct to “page.html” but with filter value ”type2”, etc.
I believe it is not possible to use href for this link, is there any other way?

Comment: What do yo mean with *filters*?

Comment: Are you aware that you will have to *post* your page? If not, read up on HTML forms. If so, where is the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with *filters*, but if you mean GET parameters, you can use JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('dropdown').onchange = function() {
    window.location.href = 'page.html?filter='+this.value;
};
```